# Create ARM parameter names dynamically

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I have a scenario where i need to generate the parameters names dynamically. Like certificate1, certificate2, certificate3 .. so on. Currently all these parameters should be defined in Main template. Can we use copy to iterate and define parameter Names dynamically in Main/Parent template?  Or is there a way in ARM templates by which this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `copy` construct in variables section or in resource definition\resource properties. and then you can use `concat()` together with `copyIndex()` function to create names.

example:

```
[concat('something-', copyIndex())]
```

this will give you names like something-0, something-1, something-2 etc. (copyIndex starts at 0). you can also choose to offset `copyIndex` by giving it an offset number:

```
[concat('something-', copyIndex(10))]
```

this will give you name like something-10, something-11, something-12 etc.

copy in variables\properties:

```
"copy": [
    {
        "name": "nameOfThePropertyOrVariableYouWantToIterateOver",
        "count": 3,
        "input": {
            "name": "[concat('something-', copyIndex('nameOfThePropertyOrVariableYouWantToIterateOver', 1))]"    
        }
    }
]
```

here you need to specify which loop are you referring to with copyIndex function and you can use offset as well

Comment: I understand that we can use copy for variables/properties. But can this similar functionality be achieved in generating Name for the parameters? Say I have a parameter file which have following parameters certificate1, certificate2, certificate3...so on. Now how can i define these parameter names in Main template(parameter section)? I think copy can only be used in variables/properties but not in parameter section right? Is there any other way

Answer (score 0):

You can use the copy function in Azure Template to generate the name of the resource, just like certificate1, certificate2, certificate3 .. so on.

Example below:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "name": "[concat('storage',copyIndex())]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS"
            },
            "kind": "Storage",
            "properties": {},
            "copy": {
                "name": "storagecopy",
                "count": 3
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

And the storage name will like these:

storage0
storage1
storage2

For more details, see [Deploy multiple instances of a resource or property in Azure Resource Manager Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-multiple).

Comment: Sure, I know what I copy. What do you mean?

Comment: check the storage names

Comment: Oh, it's my mistake. I will change it.